# SQL - Actualizar varias columnas en varias filas de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, nodejs, sqlite

Trabajo con **NodeJS** y **SQLite**, al ver mi uso del I/O de los discos SSD de mi servidor Azure (los cuales eran extremadamente altos), me gustaría hacer una seria optimización.

Mi tabla tiene el siguiente formato:

```
ID                       points         money        rep
'242043489611808769'     81086          6150         19
'158341246635606016'     62976          5604         2
'204425188480122881'     33140          0            0
'211591629486686208'     13375          2250         0
'202137748885340160'     31182          1000         7
'159730926161625088'     42907          200          0
'207174964468645889'     1243           10669        3
'179424336942202880'     12162          0            0
'170716616659566593'     13312          650          1
```

Durante todo este tiempo, siempre había estado ejecutando queries por cada línea, pero parece ser tan recursivo como muy poco eficiente.

```
UPDATE users SET points = '81086' WHERE ID = '242043489611808769'
```

Y cuando requería actualizar múltiples columnas, ejecutaba lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE users SET points = '81086', money = '6150' WHERE ID = '242043489611808769'
```

Además de tener un sistema de caché que me permite simplificar/optimizar las consultas, además de prevenir el error `SQLITE_BUSY`. El sistema actualiza la base de datos cada 30 segundos, y normalmente suele tener 3-7 columnas.

Sin embargo, ahora me gustaría que, en vez de mandar 7 consultas, mandara 1 sola, actualizando 7 filas con la posibilidad de múltiples columnas. Por ejemplo, actualizar la tabla previa a:

```
ID                       points         money        rep
'242043489611808769'     86086          6150         21
'158341246635606016'     67976          5604         2
'204425188480122881'     43140          257          0
'211591629486686208'     13375          2250         12
'202137748885340160'     31182          1000         7
'159730926161625088'     42907          200          1
'207174964468645889'     1743           10669        4
'179424336942202880'     12162          130          2
'170716616659566593'     14312          650          1
```

En la que se han editado 1-3 columnas en cada fila.

Gracias por adelanto.

Comment: el update es masivo (para muchas filas, mismo valor de columnas) o para una sola fila, muchas columnas.. pero no podes armar un query para multiples filas con multiples valores de columna. no existe eso.

Comment: Normalmente se suele actualizar 3-7 filas, con una cantidad variable de columnas, lo más normal es que se actualize la columna `points`, es la fila que más se actualiza. Existe el caso de que mi aplicación se expanda y tenga que actualizar aproximadamente 100 filas, siendo en su gran mayoría, la columna `points`.

Comment: tal vez necesites un prepare statement o lo que haya en tu lenguaje para que la consulta este precompilada y solo tengas que pasarle parametros.. asi se aceleraria.. y habria que ver como esta configurada la base de datos.. si los indices estan correctos..pero updates, solo como dije mas arriba...

Comment: Encontré la solución, ya la publiqué como respuesta. Gracias por su tiempo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución. Primero: `UPDATE <table>`, en este caso `users`. Después, actualizar una columna (`points`) con un `CASE..WHEN`, con el formato `WHEN <ID> THEN <Value>`, donde `<ID>` es la fila que se quiere actualizar (similar a `WHERE <ID>`), y `<Value>` sería el nuevo valor de la fila, en la columna seleccionada.

```
UPDATE users
SET points = CASE id
    WHEN '242043489611808769' THEN 90000
    WHEN '158341246635606016' THEN 65000
    WHEN '202245579718262784' THEN 52000
END,
money = CASE id
    WHEN '242043489611808769' THEN 4000
    WHEN '158341246635606016' THEN 9000
    WHEN '202245579718262784' THEN 15000
END
WHERE id IN ('242043489611808769','158341246635606016','202245579718262784')
```

En resumen, actualiza la tabla `users`, seleccionas la columna `points` con un CASE en la cual, cuando ID = "x", entonces actualizar su valor a "y". Terminar el case con un `END,`, y hacer lo mismo para actualizar otra columna, (y terminar con otro `END`).

Finalmente, especificar en qué filas se han actualizado.

[Fuente en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351362/update-multiple-rows-for-2-columns-in-mysql)